# Understanding the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, scheduledexecutorservice

I know that I must use this instead of `java.util.Timer` because of various reasons. So, to study this I was looking at the docs and I have a few questions:

1. How does `scheduleWithFixedDelay()` work ? *My understanding is this: It first executes a task after a given delay. Once the task is done, it waits for the specified time and then executes the task again.*
2. What happens when I submit a task to `scheduleAtFixedRate()` that takes a lot more time to execute than the specified delay ? Like I want the task to execute every 5 seconds but it takes 10 seconds to complete.  *My understanding is that the task will be held in a queue and will be executed once a core thread is available*
3. Here is my understanding of how `scheduleWithFixedDelay()` and `scheduleAtFixedRate()` differ:  `scheduleWithFixedDelay()` waits for the task to finish executing, waits for the specified time and then fires the task again where as `scheduleAtFixedRate` will just keep firing the task without caring if it has completed or not. **Correct?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Correct.
2. Not quite. If a fixed-rate task takes longer than its period, it will run again immediately upon completion, but the next run is not waiting for a thread. See below.
3. A fixed-rate task *does* care whether its previous run has completed, just like a fixed-delay task. Per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)), "If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute."

Think of it this way:

- For a fixed-delay task, you specify a period which will be the **exact** amount of time between runs. The actual duration of the task has no effect on the delay.
- For a fixed-rate task, you specify a period which will be the **maximum** amount of time between runs. If the actual duration of the task is longer than the period, the rate is reduced, and there is effectively no delay.